# Editing a string in a native dll

Tags: dll, hex

Can anyone help me edit a string in a native dll?

[image]

When I try to open the dll in CFF explorer or other similar tools, I can't see the string table, probably because it's hidden somehow.

The DLL in question is msrating.dll (Internet Ratings and Local User Management DLL), and I want to change the string:

"This Page was blocked by your Approved Sites list."

to another specific string that will guide users to another browser when they access some sites.

[Here](http://www.win7dll.info/msrating_dll.html) we can see the entire string table, but I can't seem to find them while editing the DLL.

Some guidance please :( ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can find the string resources in the [mui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilingual_User_Interface) files under the folder contains resources dedicated to localization (e.g. c:\Windows\System32\en-US). The strings are in Unicode format.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for static strings to be in the Ressource section, but that's irrelevant.

Just open the DLL in any hex editor, grep for the given string, and replace it manually. Since (from what I understand from your link) a simple *strings* shows your target, there should be no obfuscation whatsoever.